# Trying to count duplicates in a list of lists with python in two ways but getting different answers

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a data set ([here](https://www.kaggle.com/lava18/google-play-store-apps)) and I'm trying to find out how many duplicate app entries there are. I have already opened and read the data set and created a list of lists called g_play_data.
I also have the correct solution which is this:

```
unique = []
duplicate = []

for row in g_play_data:
    app_name = row[0]
    if app_name in unique:
        duplicate.append(app_name)
    else:
        unique.append(app_name)

print(len(duplicate))
```

The output is `1181`
However, I wanted to try something "better" and in one go create a frequency table using a dictionary. So this way I can count the number of duplicate apps AND also know which apps are on there and how many times that app appeared on the list.
Here's my code:

```
unique = []
duplicate = {}

for row in g_play_data:
    app_name = row[0]
    if app_name in duplicate:
        duplicate[app_name] += 1
    elif app_name in unique:
         duplicate[app_name] = 2
    else:
         unique.append(app_name)

print(len(duplicate))
```

However, the output here is `798` and I can't wrap my head around why!
My code starts the same way, and then what I'm doing is checking if the app name is already in the dictionary called duplicate, and if yes, incrementing the value of that key by 1. If not in the dictionary then I'm checking if it's already on the list of unique app names. If yes, then I'm adding that app name as key to the duplicate dictionary, and setting its value to 2 (because every app in the duplicates dictionary would have a count of at least 2). And if it's neither, then I'm adding that app name to the list called unique.
But when I run the len function on my dictionary I can't understand why I'm getting a different number than when I run the len function on the duplicate list in the first code...

Thank you.

Comment: Aren't the two ways slightly different? In the first solution every value that has been seen before is added in a list, however in the second one there will only be only one key, with a respective counter not matter how many times a value is seen. So, instead of checking the `len(duplicate)`, shouldn't you check the `sum(duplicate.values())` ?

Comment: Well in the second solution the dictionary ends up with more than one key , because every time the for loop comes across an app name that's already in the 'unique' list it adds it as a key in the dictionary with value = 2 (if it's the first time it's added to the dictionary; if the key already exists in the dictionary then the value is incremented by 1).  If I run `sum(duplicate.values())` I get 1979 which also isn't correct.

Comment: actually I think I got it! The difference in my solution was that I was trying to count how many apps were duplicates (hence counting dictionary keys) but the first solution is just counting all the duplications. If I want to match that then I should set value to 1 and not 2 when I add a new key to the duplicates dictionary! And then if I calculate the sum of values I do get the same number. Thanks!

Comment: Yes that's correct. Just replace the `+=2` with `+=1` in the elif statement of the second solution and then comparing the `len(duplicate)` of the first solution with `sum(duplicate.values())` of the second solution, will give you the same results

Answer (score 2):

Let me go straight to your mistake,

**len(list)** will count how many elements in list:

```
len(['a','b','c','a','b'])  # 5
```

**len(dict)** will count how many keys in the dictionary

```
len({'a':2, 'b':2, 'c':1})  # 2
```

#### Now even if you correct it, by summing the values of dict, you wont get same answer, WHY?

In first case, you are counting the duplicates only. ie.

```
unique = ['a','b','c']
duplicate = ['a','b']
# len(duplicate) = 2
```

In second case, you will be counting total number of items, because, if element already exist in the dict. i.e. count=1 and encountered again 2nd time (count is set to 2)

```
# len(SUM_OF_VALUES_OF_KEYS) = len(unique) + len(duplicate)
```

#### So whats the best way to solve this the second way?

**defaultdict**: python has this enhanced feature dictionary, that sets default value to key if key is not present.

```
from collections import defaultdict
counter = defaultdict(lambda: 0)  # set 0 (to count total items), set -1 (to count duplicate items)
for row in g_play_data:
    app_name = row[0]
    counter[app_name] += 1
print(sum(counter.values())
```

Comment: thank you, I think where I tripped up is that for some reason I assumed the "duplicate" list in the first solution had unique elements, I didn't realise the same element could appear there twice which you highlighted. Hence why I assumed that len of that list should match the count of keys in my dictionary.